# Converting scientific notation to human readable float

Tags: python

How can I programmatically take a float like this:

```
1.87491348956e-28
```

and convert it into a float (likely a string) like this:

```
0.000000000000000000000000000187491348956
```

(I think that's the right number of zeros)

Comment: So... scientist are not human? ;-) Seriously, I find above notation much more readable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a=1.87491348956e-28
base,expo = str(a).split('e')
print '%%1.%df'%(len(base)-2+abs(int(expo)))%a
```

Edit: I forgot to remove some formatting parts. The latest version is a little shorter.

How does it work?

You could call the format string a recursive one. In a first step only the inner part, i.e. `%d` is interpreted as format information and replaced by the calculated length of the floating point number. Let's call that length X. Thus, after the first formatting, the remaining format string reads `%1.Xf` and is used to actually format the number. Note that the `%%` got replaced by a single `%` after the first step.

**Edit:**

Rob_sigma added a comment with an easier solution:

```
a=1.87491348956e-28
base,expo = str(a).split('e')
print '%.*f'%(len(base)-2+abs(int(expo)),a)
```

I must admit that I have never seen that syntax before.

Comment: well yea if you really want to show off  lol, but that is really a great solution

Comment: Wow... looks like your cat jumped on your keyboard, but it works. Could you add a bit of explanation, though?

Comment: @tobias_k I create a dynamic formatting string from the length of the base and the exponent, e.g. `'%%1.%df'%23` -> `'%1.23f'`

Comment: @tobias_k I see. You are saying that I should add it to my answer?

Comment: `print '%.*f'%(len(base)-2+abs(int(expo)),a)` seems more readable than invoking the `%` operator twice.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have never seen that `*` syntax before.

Answer (score 1):

count the number of digits after the decimal you have and add the + exponent to get the output precision:

```
'%.39f' % 1.87491348956e-28
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers, I was able to create what I wanted:

```
f = 1.23456789e-28
d = abs(int(str(f).split('e')[1]))
print format(f, '.{0}f'.format(d)) + ' %'
```

The difference is that the function above will automatically make a human-readable float that is always exactly as many digits as are necessary.  Also, I can do a "d += 10" or similar to add additional significant digits.

Here's some example output to see what I mean:

```
0.0000000000000000000000000000003 %
0.0000000000000000000000000000006 %
0.0000000000000000000000000000009 %
0.000000000000000000000000000001 %
0.000000000000000000000000000001 %
0.000000000000000000000000000002 %
0.000000000000000000000000000002 %
0.000000000000000000000000000002 %
0.000000000000000000000000000003 %
0.000000000000000000000000000003 %
0.000000000000000000000000000003 %
0.000000000000000000000000000004 %
0.000000000000000000000000000004 %
0.000000000000000000000000000004 %
0.000000000000000000000000000004 %
0.000000000000000000000000000005 %
0.000000000000000000000000000005 %
0.000000000000000000000000000005 %
0.000000000000000000000000000006 %
0.000000000000000000000000000006 %
0.000000000000000000000000000006 %
0.000000000000000000000000000006 %
0.000000000000000000000000000007 %
0.000000000000000000000000000007 %
0.000000000000000000000000000007 %
0.000000000000000000000000000008 %
0.000000000000000000000000000008 %
0.000000000000000000000000000008 %
0.000000000000000000000000000009 %
0.000000000000000000000000000009 %
0.000000000000000000000000000009 %
0.000000000000000000000000000009 %
0.000000000000000000000000000010 %
0.000000000000000000000000000010 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000001 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
0.00000000000000000000000000002 %
```

See how as the number gets larger, the resulting float gets shorter to match.

Comment: Well rather than distilling others' answers to answer yourself you should accept one of those answers, I guess.

Comment: @ChristianK. At the time, your answer hadn't existed yet, or I would have chosen it as the correct one.  In fact, I will still choose yours as the correct one, and just let mine sit.

Comment: You can get the same effect with only one call to format and no string addition: `'print {:.{:}f} %'.format(f, d)`